# Using an IF statement in SQL to determine whether an email is sent

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, if-statement, stored-procedures

I currently have a stored procedure (Utils.DailySalesTaxDue) that calculates the sum of a field (SalesTax).  Currently the the procedure will determine the amount and then execute another sproc (Utils.SendEmail).

There are times when the sum of SalesTax equals $0.00.  In these cases, I do not want to have an email sent out.  I assume an IF statement is needed.  I have an if statement that is using a wildcard statement to check for %$0.00% within the @ReportBody variable.  It works, however I know this is probably not the best way to do this.  This is what I currently have.

```
declare @ReportHTML varchar(max), 
            @Recipient varchar(255), 
            @EmailSubject varchar(255), 
            @ReportBody varchar(max)
select 
        @ReportBody = 'Sales Tax Total due is: <b>' + format(isnull(sum(SalesTax),0.00),'C','en-us') + '</b>'
    from 
        Final.FactTransactionDay f
            inner join Final.SaleOutcome so
                on  f.SaleOutcomeKey = so.SaleOutcomekey
    where
        f.StoreID = @StoreID and 
        f.=TransactionDateKey = @TransactionDateKey and
        so.NetCount <> 0

/////Additional Code

--Do not send the email if claim amount is $0.00
    if @ReportBody not like '%$0.00%'
    begin
        --Send email
        exec Utils.SendEmail
                @HTML = @ReportHtml,
                @Recipients = @Recipient,
                @From = 'NoReply@SalesSupport.net',
                @FromName = 'Sales',
                @Subject = @EmailSubject
    end
```

What would be a better approach to checking whether sum(SalesTax) is not equal to $0.00, and if it is not equal to then fire off the Utils.SendEmail stored procedure?

Comment: I would assign the result of `Sum(SalesTax)` to a different variable and checking that result instead of doing a `LIKE` on the entire body of the email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An aggregation query is always going to return at least one row.  Your code is likely going to make `@ReportBody` have a `NULL` value . . . except for the `isnull()`.  I would go for:

```
declare @ReportHTML varchar(max), 
        @Recipient varchar(255), 
        @EmailSubject varchar(255), 
        @ReportBody varchar(max),
        @Count int;

select @ReportBody = 'Sales Tax Total due is: <b>' + format(isnull(sum(SalesTax),0.00),'C','en-us') + '</b>',
       @Count = count(*)
from Final.FactTransactionDay f inner join
     Final.SaleOutcome so
     on f.SaleOutcomeKey = so.SaleOutcomekey
where f.StoreID = @StoreID and 
      f.TransactionDateKey = @TransactionDateKey and
      so.NetCount <> 0;

if @count > 0
begin
    . . .
end;
```

If you like, you can check `sum()` instead of `count()`.  I'm thinking that you want to send the email if anything actually matches.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
DECLARE @ReportHTML varchar(max), 
        @Recipient varchar(255), 
        @EmailSubject varchar(255), 
        @SalesTaxTotal double,
        @ReportBody varchar(max)

SELECT
    @SalesTaxTotal = ISNULL(SUM(SalesTax),0.00),
    @ReportBody = 'Sales Tax Total due is: <b>' + FORMAT(ISNULL(SUM(SalesTax),0.00),'C','en-us') + '</b>'
FROM
    Final.FactTransactionDay f
    INNWE JOIN Final.SaleOutcome so on f.SaleOutcomeKey = so.SaleOutcomekey
WHERE
    f.StoreID = @StoreID
    AND f.TransactionDateKey = @TransactionDateKey
    AND so.NetCount <> 0

--Do not send the email if claim amount is $0.00
IF (@SalesTaxTotal != 0.00)
BEGIN
    --Send email
    EXEC Utils.SendEmail
            @HTML = @ReportHtml,
            @Recipients = @Recipient,
            @From = 'NoReply@SalesSupport.net',
            @FromName = 'Sales',
            @Subject = @EmailSubject
END
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

`if CHARINDEX('$0.00', @ReportBody ) = 0`